# I have installed ubuntu alongside windows 10 (UEFI). I can't run efibootmgr to select BOOT ORDER IN UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, usb-installation

I know without this I can't run Ubuntu. I have installed ubuntu in this machine before but didn't find any way to load the OS in the UEFI or at startup.

I am following the guide here: 
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

But when I type sudo efibootmgr, I get the message- efibootmgr: EFI variables are not supported on this system.

[image]

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? And what brand/model system? Many require work arounds, but different by brand. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Chances are you've installed Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, whereas Windows was in EFI/UEFI mode. There are a ton of questions here about similar issues, but my searches are finding too many hits that aren't *quite* right. Try [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611031/problem-dual-booting-windows-with-efi-and-2-hard-disks/613232) as a starting point. Also, read [my page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) on the issue for more background.

Answer (score 0):

For me the only working solution was to change the Boot order in the BIOS. Changing it from Windows 10 or Ubuntu did have no effect.

My theory on that is, that the UEFI system locks its partition after boot to restrict access.

PS: I have a relatively new MSI Laptop.

Comment: *Windows* can cause problems with ESP access because of its Fast Startup feature, which *must* be disabled (as described [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)) for safety. You may also need to [disable hibernation](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) in Windows. An EFI shouldn't "lock" partitions. You may also have run into an EFI-vs-BIOS/CSM/legacy boot issue.

Comment: I'm sure i did install both systems in UEFI mode. I disabled Fast Mode after Installation, so i guess it should be fine. There is also an MSI Recovery Partition which could cause the issues.